# Linux's Packages updates

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, yum, apt-get

I'm trying to reset a Windows's password I have on a computer through a Debian distribution I have on the same machine, the best way for doing this is with a package u can apt-get called chntpw, the problem is that the version is old and I'ts not useful. However there is a newer version I got on Fedora through yum.
I'm wondering how to do this 2 things:

1. How can I convert the .rpm (yum) package to a functional .deb (apt-get) one?
2. How can I upload that package to the Debian's repository so nobody else have the problem I had today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alien tool to install rpm packages in debian based distributions, see here: http://www.debianadmin.com/install-rpm-files-in-debian-and-ubuntu.html

To get the newest release into the official debian repository you have to package the software (most probably that can be done by using the old package as a template) and then get some debian developer to sponsor it for you so it will be allowed into the system.

Comment: than you for answering